# Is there any way to determine if a Firefox WebExtension is installed from the store or locally?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

Ich have updated my Google Chrome Extension so it runs as a Firefox WebExtension, too. To not manually update the server address from my local dev server to the production server every time I publish the extension, I test for `chrome.runtime.getManifest().update_url`. In Chrome only the version from the store has this field. In Firefox there is no such thing.

Is there any other test that works for both browsers?

Comment: Interesting need. I don't know if this is possible. I never came across anyone doing this in classic or SDK firefox extensions. Just out of curiosity - this is unrelated - why do you need this functionality? It is very unlikely anyone installs from locally, its actually not allowed. Only way is to load as temporary addon - https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/12/23/loading-temporary-add-ons/

Comment: I needed this to distinguish between dev (local) and prod (from the store) and chose the correct backend api host. Without this I always have to set it manually before publishing the extension.

Comment: Would those have different versions? You can easily check version is installed. I know I'm taking this to an XY problem, but I just don't think there is a way to get this info locale/store.

Comment: Some automation for the whole web extension development process would be nice. Right now it's a bit tedious (packing & installing every time I make a change is somewhat cruel on the developer :-)